# send data from view to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to send some data from view to controller in rails through ajax.

I have the following code in
app/view/static/home.html.erb

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var dummy = "testtext";
        $('#finish').click(function() {
          $.ajax( {
            url: '/finish',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dummy,
            dataType: 'text'
          });
         });
      </script>

      <body>
        <%= button_to "Finish", {:action => 'finish', :controller => 'static'}, :method => :post, id => 'finish' %>
      </body>
```

in 
app/view/static/finish.html.erb

```
<p><%= @data %></p>
```

app/controller/static_controller.rb

```
def finish
@data = params[:data]
end
```

in routes.rb

```
post 'finish' => 'static#finish'
```

My understanding is that on button click the ajax script will be executed and rails action will store the data passed from view. This doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if my understanding of the flow is right.

Comment: Try sending a JSON request instead. Rails will not parse the request body into the parameters for a `text/plain` request.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling params[:data] in the controller, you need to specify that {data: dummy} in the AJAX data section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dummy = "testtext";
    $('#finish').click(function() {
      $.ajax( {
        url: '/finish',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data: dummy},
        dataType: 'text'
      });
     });
  </script>
```

Also you might want to respond to your AJAX call in your controller using the following

```
def finish
  @data = params[:data]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { insert_your_code_here }
  end
end
```

Comment: You may also need `return false` at the end of the click() function - otherwise the browser will start sending the ajax request, then also submit the `button_to` form, resulting in the action being hit twice